# Determining xml pattern and length of variables in xml coding

Tags: xml, functional-programming

```
  <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="Surname">
                <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                <xs:maxLength value="70"/>
                <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"/>
                </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>

            </xs:element>
```

I have an xml code written as above meant to capture surname with minLength 1 and max of 70, will the code above accept any surname with length between 1 to 70? or will the pattern value limit the length of the surname? If the pattern value will limit it, how many will it return and how should it have been written to process the required length between the min and max length?

Answer (score 0):

> or will the pattern value limit the length of the surname?

Yes it will.

The pattern is defined as accepting three letters (lower or upper case) only.

Given you're limiting the length elsewhere, you should be able to use a pattern that allows for any length:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

However note, that many people have surnames that will not match. Eg. "O'Donnel" and such which have an apostrophe, or double-barrelled names with a hyphen.

Generally with names (people and places) any simple rule you try and create to only allow "correct" names will have plenty of valid exceptions: you're just blocking people from using your system. See *[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)*.

Comment: Does the above xml coding i posted implies I can only accept 3 Letters surname ONLY even with the min and max length stated in the code?

Comment: @Center Correct. The regex has to match the complete potential value (there is an implied beginning of and end of text marker around the XSD regex – unlike other regex varieties).